# AsyncTask Not throws exception in Android 2.3 Andengine

Tags: android, multithreading, andengine

I have a code which successfully runs in Google Nexus(Android 4.2). But when I tried it yesterday in a lower version with android 2.3.5 it throws an Exception.

Please help me resolve the same.

Details.

I created a class `DownloadHelper` which help me download a file from internet to a location in my phone.
This class intern calls a sub class `DownloadFile extends AsyncTask`. When I try to create a object of `DownloadFile` it throws the exception.

Below is the code of `DownloadHeper`

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.andengine.entity.text.Text;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

import com.gretrainer.gretrainer.StartingScreen;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class DownloadHelper {
    public void loadFile(String url,Text loadingT,BaseGameActivity activity1,String _filename,int _tag){
        DownloadFile downloadFile;
        try {
            downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
            loadingText = loadingT;
            activity = activity1;
            downloadFile.execute(url);
            StartingPercent = 0;
            EndingPercent = 100;
            filename = _filename;
            tag = _tag;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("exec",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }



    }

    private int tag;
    private String filename;
    private float StartingPercent;
    private float EndingPercent;
    private BaseGameActivity activity;
    private Text loadingText;
    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{

        public DownloadFile(){

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString().concat(File.separator + filename));


                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
                StartingScreen act = (StartingScreen)activity;
                act.onLoadFileComplete(tag);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String message = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                Log.d("hello",message);
            }
            return null;
        }

          @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });
                //loadingText.setText(StartingPercent + ((EndingPercent - StartingPercent) / 100) * progress[0] + "%");
            }


    }
}
```

The exception is thrown when it executes the line downloadFile = new DownloadFile();

The details of Exception is as shown below.

```
UpdateThread interrupted. Don't worry - this EngineDestroyedException is most likely expected!
org.andengine.engine.Engine$EngineDestroyedException
```

It goes back to last line of `onCreateScene`. but the app is freezed. 
It works fine in new android os(4.2)

Please check

Entire log from the time of exception
04-07 17:46:42.498: W/dalvikvm(2552): Exception Ljava/lang/RuntimeException; thrown while initializing Landroid/os/AsyncTask;
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552): StartingScreen.onPopulateScene failed. @(Thread: 'GLThread 11')
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at com.gretrainer.gretrainer.AppHelpers.DownloadHelper.loadFile(DownloadHelper.java:24)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at com.gretrainer.gretrainer.StartingScreen.onPopulateScene(StartingScreen.java:102)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$2.onCreateSceneFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:154)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at com.gretrainer.gretrainer.StartingScreen.onCreateScene(StartingScreen.java:91)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$3.onCreateResourcesFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:169)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at com.gretrainer.gretrainer.StartingScreen.onCreateResources(StartingScreen.java:68)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:181)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:110)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:80)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1352)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1122)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.(AsyncTask.java:421)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.(AsyncTask.java:421)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  at android.os.AsyncTask.(AsyncTask.java:152)
04-07 17:47:06.891: E/AndEngine(2552):  ... 11 more
04-07 17:47:06.891: D/AndEngine(2552): StartingScreen.onSurfaceChanged(Width=320,  Height=480) @(Thread: 'GLThread 11')
04-07 17:47:07.102: D/dalvikvm(2552): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 142K, 42% free 3211K/5447K, external 1K/512K, paused 26ms
04-07 17:47:07.102: I/dalvikvm-heap(2552): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.457MB for 1382416-byte allocation
04-07 17:47:07.222: D/dalvikvm(2552): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 34% free 4559K/6855K, external 1K/512K, paused 3ms+4ms
04-07 17:47:07.222: D/AndEngine(2552): StartingScreen.onResumeGame @(Thread: 'main')
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.gretrainer.gretrainer/databases/GreApp' 
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1960)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:906)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:940)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:933)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:744)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:198)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at com.gretrainer.gretrainer.AppHelpers.DatabaseHandler.getWordsCount(DatabaseHandler.java:213)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at com.gretrainer.gretrainer.StartingScreen.onPopulateScene(StartingScreen.java:100)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$2.onCreateSceneFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:154)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at com.gretrainer.gretrainer.StartingScreen.onCreateScene(StartingScreen.java:91)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$3.onCreateResourcesFinished(BaseGameActivity.java:169)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at com.gretrainer.gretrainer.StartingScreen.onCreateResources(StartingScreen.java:68)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateGame(BaseGameActivity.java:181)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onSurfaceCreated(BaseGameActivity.java:110)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EngineRenderer.java:80)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1352)
04-07 17:47:07.292: E/Database(2552):   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1122)

Comment: Add the whole log... it's much easier when you can see the entire stack trace...

Comment: I have added the whole log. Please check @StevenByle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a guess but several of the `Exceptions` lead to the conclusion that you are not executing the `AsyncTask` correctly (see `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`. I am not suggesting, calling `Looper.prepare()` by yourself, but executing the `Asynctask` on another thread. So instead of

```
downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
loadingText = loadingT;
activity = activity1;
downloadFile.execute(url);
StartingPercent = 0;
EndingPercent = 100;
filename = _filename;
tag = _tag;
```

try something like this (btw, you are accessing some variables within your task, that should be initialized earlier):

```
loadingText = loadingT;
activity = activity1;   
StartingPercent = 0;
EndingPercent = 100;
filename = _filename;
tag = _tag; 
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new DownloadFile().execute(url);
    }
});
```

My experience with `AsyncTask`s is, that they shouldn't run on the normal `Update Thread`, since this thread is for refreshing the screen only, so try running it on the `UIThread` instead (Since you are not displaying data directly from within the task).